# Installing Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) on Ubuntu Linux using YUM

Tags: oracle, installation, ubuntu-14.04, oracle18c

I am trying to install Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Release 18.4.0.0.0 (18c) on Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux) using yum and receive the following errors:

```
~/my_oracle# yum localinstall oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
Marking oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-database-xe-18c.x86_64 0:1.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: file for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: net-tools for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: oracle-database-preinstall-18c for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: file
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: net-tools
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: oracle-database-preinstall-18c
Error: Package: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64 (/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64)
           Requires: /bin/sh
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Just trying to follow instructions and unfortunately to no avail.

I am using these instructions here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/procedure-installing-oracle-database-xe.html

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 18c XE edition does not support Ubuntu but you can install 12c or 11g.Lastly be careful when trying install rpms because ubuntu package management system is not rpm. You can use alien and convert rpm to deb but it's not efficient.Oracle 18c supports CentOS, Red Hat,SUSE linux distros.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/operating-system-requirements-for-x86-64-linux-platforms.html#GUID-3F647617-7FF5-4EE4-BBA8-9A5E3EEC888F

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't think Oracle really supports Ubuntu. The errors say that you are missing some other packages (file, net-tools, oracle-database-preinstall-18c and strangely enough /bin/sh), so on a Red Hat based system you could simply let yum install them. My advice would be to switch to CentOS or another Red Hat based OS if you can.

If not, see for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1095737/how-to-install-oracle-18c-xe-rpm-package-on-ubuntu-18-04 which recommends installing alien and using it to convert the rpm to a deb file, which can be installed by the native package manager. I haven't tried it personally with XE 18, but it worked with XE 11.

Comment: Can we use oracle xe using docker?
Or install Redhat or Centos on a vm machine and use it in network?

Comment: This is a very old question. I would advise you to check Oracle's documentation first. However, technically there is nothing that prevents you from using Oracle XE in Docker or on a VM. In fact I have been doing that in many projects in development environments over the years. Just make sure that you don't break the license in some way.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to convert RPM into Deb package with this command:

alien --script oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

alien --script oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0–1.x86_64.rpm

**[Oracle 18c XE installation on Debian 10 (Buster)](https://medium.com/@kenny.chlim/oracle-18c-xe-installation-debian-10-4-buster-9cbf7f957d9f)**